# Yii2 вставка js скоиптов

Tags: yii2

Всем привет!
Для вставки кода скрипта использую shaqman/yii2-inline-script
Подключаю так:

```
<?php use shaqman\widgets\inlinescript\InlineScript; ?>
 <?php InlineScript::begin(); ?>
 <script>

  $(window).on('load', function () {
        $preloader = $('.preloader'),
        $loader = $preloader.find('.prePreloader');
        $loader.fadeOut();
        $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
  });

</script>
<?php InlineScript::end(); ?>
```

Все как написано, но код всередине  обрезается
и плучается вот так:

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {
     = $('.preloader'),
       = .find('.prePreloader');
    .fadeOut();
    .delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
  });
```

Естественно это вызывает ошибку, кто нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Сам разодбрался.
Если использовать в коде js в названии переменно1 $, то она почемуто вырезается

```
$preloader = $('.preloader'),
$loader = $preloader.find('.prePreloader');
```

надо без них:

```
preloader = $('.preloader'),
loader = preloader.find('.prePreloader');
```